# How to find Processor Group number using WMIC

Tags: wmic

On Intel systems > 64 processors they break the processors into Group for easy addressing. For example a system with 72 processors will have Group 0 and Group 1 with 36 processors in each group. The following gets me the Processor group count.

```
pGetMaximumProcessorGroupCount = (PROC_ADDR_GMPGC) GetProcAddress(hmod, "GetMaximumProcessorGroupCount")
```

*How can I get the group count and Group Number using wmic.exe?*

Initially I wanted to get the number of processors from the wmic command line so I typed `cpu get -?` but it did not list any useful options. However another Stack Over answer mentioned:

```
wmic:root\cli>cpu get NumberOfCores NumberOfLogicalProcessors/Format:List
```

and it works fine.

*How can I find the unlisted option `NumberOfCores` and `NumberOfLogicalProcessors`?* Please point me to documentation URL that might answer my first question too.

**Answer to my second question:**

```
wmic:root\cli>cpu get
AddressWidth  Architecture  Availability  Caption
64            9             3             Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5
64            9             3             Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5
ConfigManagerErrorCode  ConfigManagerUserConfig  CpuStatus  CreationClassName
                                                 1          Win32_Processor
                                                 1          Win32_Processor
CurrentClockSpeed  CurrentVoltage  DataWidth  Description
3193              12              64         Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5
3193              12              64         Intel64 Family 6 Model 26 Stepping 5
DeviceID  ErrorCleared  ErrorDescription  ExtClock  Family  InstallDate  L2CacheSize
CPU0                                      133       179                  1024
CPU1                                      133       179                  1024
L2CacheSpeed  L3CacheSize  L3CacheSpeed  LastErrorCode  Level  LoadPercentage
              8192         0                            6      96
              8192         0                            6      12
Manufacturer  MaxClockSpeed  Name
GenuineIntel  3193           Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           W5580  @ 3.20GHz
GenuineIntel  3193           Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           W5580  @ 3.20GHz
NumberOfCores  NumberOfLogicalProcessors  OtherFamilyDescription  PNPDeviceID
4              8
4              8
PowerManagementCapabilities  PowerManagementSupported  ProcessorId  ProcessorType
                             FALSE                     BFEBFBFF000106A5  3
                             FALSE                     BFEBFBFF000106A5  3
Revision  Role  SocketDesignation  Status  StatusInfo  Stepping
6661      CPU   CPU1               OK      3
6661      CPU   CPU2               OK      3
SystemCreationClassName  SystemName      UniqueId  UpgradeMethod  Version  VoltageCaps
Win32_ComputerSystem     AGVARDHA-DESK2            25
Win32_ComputerSystem     AGVARDHA-DESK2            25
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Trooper for formatting it nicely even I understood it better. I did find answer to second question. Just wmic:root\cli>cpu get lists it only thing it is not intuitive because it stretches to the right and to scroll right is not obvious. So this is how it looks. For clarity I have broken it into multiple lines

Comment: `wmic cpu get NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors`